# how to obtain this differential EQ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Consider the initial value problem
> $$
> \frac{dy}{dt}  = \frac{ty (4-y)}{3}, \quad y(0) = y_0.
> $$
> Determine how the behavior of the solution as $t$ increases depends on the initial value $y_0$.

I use this eq is separable, so
$$
\begin{split}
\left(\frac1y - \frac1{4-y}\right)dy &= \frac43 t dt \\
\ln |y| - \ln |4-y| &= \frac23 t^2 +c 
\end{split}
$$
and since $y(0)=y_0$, we have $c=\ln\left|\frac{y_0}{4-y_0}\right|$.

Book solution said $y_0=0 \implies y=0$, why is it?
$y_0=0 \implies c=0$, so as $t \to \infty$, $\ln\left| \frac{y}{4-y}\right| \to \infty$, so $y \to 4$ isn't it?

but book said $y_0>0 \implies y \to 4, y_0<0 \implies y\to -\infty$, i don't understand this sol, how to prove this questions and how to obtain this dif-EQ?

Comment: Use MathJax to improve readability anx show your efforts.

Comment: sry.. i edited. dy/dt = ty(4-y)/3

Answer (score 1):

$${dy\over dt}={ty(4-y)\over3} \implies \ln\left({y\over 4-y}\right)={2\over3}t^2+C$$
Which yields;

$$ {y\over4-y}=Ae^{{2\over3}t^2} \implies y(t)={4Ae^{{2\over3}t^2}\over(1+Ae^{{2\over3}t^2})}$$

Using the initial condition, $y(0)=y_0$, Allows us to solve for A;

$$y(0)={4A\over1+A}=y_0 \implies A={y_0\over4-y_0}$$

So our final solution is;

$$y(t)={4y_0e^{{2\over3}t^2}\over\left(4-y_0(1-e^{{2\over3}t^2})\right)}$$

So, if $y_0=0$ then we do, indeed, have $y(t)=0$, as required.